# Jxls: Transformer is null

Tags: java, android, maven, transformer-model, jxls

I am using Jxls to write data into an excel file.

For that I have a xls template `R.raw.object_collection_xmlbuilder_template_products_list` which is in `*/res>raw` folder and xml builder file `R.xml.excel_template_products_list` is in `*/res>xml` folder .

```
try (InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.object_collection_xmlbuilder_template_products_list)) {
                try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(excel_file)) {
                    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is, os);

                    try (InputStream configInputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(+R.xml.excel_template_products_list)) {

                        AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XmlAreaBuilder(configInputStream, transformer);
                        List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
                        Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);

                        org.jxls.common.Context context = new org.jxls.common.Context();
                        context.putVar("products", hashmap_list);

                        xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Result!A1"), context);
                        transformer.write();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    aLog.error(ex);
        }
```

But Transformer Object is returning as null.
And for line `List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();`, it throws :

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'
exception.org.jxls.builder.xml.AreaAction
```

These are the `jar` files I had added:

```
'libs/jxls-2.4.0.jar'
'libs/jxls-poi-1.0.12.jar'
'libs/slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar'
```

One solution suggested that I add the maven dependency, like so:

```
maven {
        url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    }
```

But I still get the exception.

So, any idea why could the transformer be null and how can I fix the exception ? Thank you.

Edit:
This is xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xls>
    <area ref="Template!A1:T31">
        <each items="products" var="products" ref="Template!A4:T31">
            <area ref="Template!A4:T31"/>
        </each>
    </area>
</xls>
```

This is the xls template:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the [jxls-demo](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo) project repo to see how the Jxls dependencies are configured for Maven project.